# Cannot use column names in SQL queries of DashDB/"Db2 Warehouse on Cloud"

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I loaded some sample data into Db2 Warehouse on Cloud but I'm not able to execute even basic SQL queries since I'm always getting "QL0206N: SQL0206N "[column_name]" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703".

for example: `select log_id from m1`

I tried multiple variants like 
`select m1.log_id from m1` 
`select m1.log_id from dash6792.m1` 
`select message.log_id from dash6792.m1 as message` => still getting the same error.

I also tried different columns and tried to put them into different places of the query (e.g. in "where" or "on" clauses) => the same result.

Surprisingly, I can query tables from sample schemas (e.g. "GOSALES") normally => so the problem occurs only for my schema (but for all tables).

Comment: What does `describe table` return for your  schema.table-name ?

Comment: Try `select "log_id" from m1`

Comment: mao, ironically, `describe table DASH6792.M1` also appeared to be syntactically incorrect.  =>  " SQL0104N An unexpected token "DASH6792" was found following "describe table ". Expected tokens may include: "JOIN". SQLSTATE=42601". I tried the double quotes as well.

Comment: mustaccio, double qoutes did the trick. I was sure I tried that as well, but apparently that was not the case - when I double checked it after your comment it worked! Thank you!